# Want to match user password in controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm using loopback and having model name BaseUser. I want to update user password only if user enters correct old password. But in the baseUser object their is no property for password so I can't match them. How can I match the user password.

please guide me into this.

Comment: Why do you need to show the password at all? It's not secure. Moreover, passwords are usually stored as a hash, so you can't get the real password out of it

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin I want to update password only if user enters the correct old password. So i don't to display it but want to compare the password is their any way?

Comment: The framework should support changing the password server-side. Keeping the password or even it's hash in the front-end is not secure. You can make an ajax call to your backend to check if the old password is correct

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin that's what i'm asking how to match password in loopback.io framework i wont display it on front end. Any idea??

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin i've already gone thru the doc.where i can compare the old password enter by user.

Comment: So, what the problem then?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin sorry i made a typing mistake i want to wright "i've already gone thru the doc.where i can compare the old password enter by user".

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-faq-user-management#how-do-you-perform-a-password-reset-for-a-registered-user) says:

1. Create a form to gather password reset info
2. Create an endpoint to handle the password reset request. Calling `User.resetPassword` ultimately emits a `resetPasswordRequest` event and creates a temporary access token
3. Register an event handler for the `resetPasswordRequest` that sends an email to the registered user. In our example, we provide a URL that redirects the user to a password reset page authenticated with a temporary access token
4. Create a password reset form for the user to enter and confirm their new password
5. Create an endpoint to process the password reset